# What is wrong with my JSON in this Oauth Request?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, rest

I'm struggling to implement a 2 legged OAuth post request into my NodeJS application. I am trying to post information to the Schoology API (https://developers.schoology.com/) and I can't seem to successfully do that. My code right now:

```
function postCourse(){
    r.post("https://api.schoology.com/v1/courses", null, null,"{'title': 'English Writing', 'course_code': 'E101', 'department': 'English','description': 'Essay Writing'}","application/json", function (err, data, res) {
    console.log(res);   
    });
}
```

I keep getting a 400 response... bad request. What am I doing wrong? I am using the same line of code to `GET` things from the API and it works.

As answered below, the bad request was thrown due to the use of single quotes instead of double quotes. This is a JSON problem, not an OAuth problem. The correct JSON should look like this:
`{\"title\": \"English Writing\", \"course_code\": \"E101\", \"department\": \"English\",\"description\": \"Essay Writing\"}`, using a backslash as an escape character for the double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An HTTP status code of 400 means "Bad Request"  - your request was somehow malformed or not parse-able by the server.

I notice that you're passing JSON like this:

`{'title': 'English Writing', 'course_code': 'E101', 'department': 'English', 'description': 'Essay Writing'}`

However, you cannot use single quotes in JSON. You must use double quotes, like this:

`{"title": "English Writing", "course_code": "E101", "department": "English", "description": "Essay Writing"}`

If you fix this error and make sure that your API request adheres to their API guidelines the 400 Bad Request error should go away.

Comment: You are right.... I'm just an idiot lol. I've been dealing with REST APIs and JSON a lot lately, I can't believe I made this mistake... Thank you! It works.